# It seems that UWP Async IO is real async operations only since 10.0.17763, but not real before. How to explain that?

Tags: uwp, async-await, deadlock, windows-10-universal

Just write this simple codes below in your `MainPage`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // It is not recommended to call Wait() in a UI thread. I write this only for a test.
    DoAsync().Wait();
    // This line enters on 10.0.17134 / 10.0.16299
    // and never enters on 10.0.17763.
}

private async Task DoAsync()
{
    await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("walterlv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

#### Targeting 10.0.17134 or lower

Commonly, if the `DoAsync` is a real async operation, the `Wait()` will cause a deadlock. But if you run the `Button_Click`, you'll find that the deadlock does not happen.

Try to click the button several times, and you'll see the deadlock happen after a random click counting.

I've tried 10.0.116299, too.

#### Targeting 10.0.17763

The deadlock occurs immediately when you click the button.

#### My confusing

What's the difference between the async operations above or below 10.0.17134?

**Notice**: It is not recommended to call `Wait()` or `Result` in a UI thread, but I'm confused about the different behavior between them, so I've written the testing code above.

Comment: This is odd.  I almost feel that it's a problem with creating the folder and not the ```Wait()``` in this situation; if this is all the code.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes it's all the code and anybody can copy and paste the code to reproduce this problem. I also think that the behavior of `CreateFileAsync` has changed from sometimes async to always async.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have time to ATM but I do plan to try and reproduce this because it is odd to me.